# git subtree pull rebase error

Tags: git, git-subtree

I added one repo as subtree, when I run `git pull -s subtree projectB master`, everything is as expected, but get fatal when switch to `rebase merge` with `git pull --rebase -s subtree projectB master`. Log:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
fatal: Could not parse object 'd2c2b2d5548fab404e1fccfa1fc22da3d5a6151c^'
Unknown exit code (128) from command: git-merge-subtree d2c2b2d5548fab404e1fccfa1fc22da3d5a6151c^ -- HEAD d2c2b2d5548fab404e1fccfa1fc22da3d5a6151c
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

*[edit] I believe subtree depends on the tree hash remaining the same to maintain the path and rebase doesn't.*

I've run into this using subtree. If your configs have rebase=true
such as `branch.master.rebase=true` and `pull.rebase=true` it will defeat the subtree.

It seems there was a documentation [recommendation](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-subtree-merge-strategy-fails-if-branch-master-rebase-true-tp3330677.html) that never got merged (this looks like a [howto page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) you may be using)...

In my case a quick `git config pull.rebase false` did the trick. Tweaking `git config branch.master.rebase false` should help that repo sync.